# Specifying a space in inches between columns in a tabular environment

Tags: tables

I would like to have a space of `2.5in` between columns in a `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\usepackage{makecell}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}


\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{3.) }In the preceding figure, $\triangle\mathit{CEF}$ is an equilateral triangle with edge length $x$, $\mathit{ABCD}$ is a square with edge length $x$, and vertices $C$, $D$, and $E$ are collinear. $\mathit{APQR}$ is a rectangle enclosing the triangle and rectangle. If the length of the diagonals of the rectangle is $d$, compute $d^{2}/x^{2}$.
\noindent \hspace*{2em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.6in}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}lr@{}l}
\textbf{a.) }       &   $\displaystyle{\frac{23 + 4\sqrt{3}}{4}}$
&
\textbf{b.) }      &   $\displaystyle{\frac{25 + 4\sqrt{3}}{4}}$\\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{c.) }     &   $\displaystyle{\frac{25 + 4\sqrt{3}}{3}}$
&
\textbf{d.) }      &   $\displaystyle{\frac{25 + 4\sqrt{5}}{3}}$\\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{e.) }       &   $\displaystyle{\frac{27 + 4\sqrt{7}}{3}}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Between which columns? `@{\hspace{2.5in}}` instead of `@{}` or between `l` and `r`?

Comment: @Schweinebacke  There are two columns.

Comment: @Schweinebacke  I tried putting `@{\hspace{2.5in}}` between `l` and `r`.  The display showed about twice that distance between the columns.

Comment: There are four columns!

Comment: @Schweinebacke  There are two columns.  Did you compile my code?

Comment: I see the code. You have `@{}r@{}lr@{}l` as column declaration. This is: `@{}` = no initial column separation; `r` = right aligned column (1st column), `@{}` = no column separation, `l` = left aligned column (2nd column), `r` = right aligned column (3rd column), `@{}` = no column separation, `l` = left aligned column (4th column). And the 3 `&` in the rows also separate 4 columns. So you are wrong: You habe 4 columns.

Comment: @Schweinebacke  The display is two columns.  To typeset `a.)` and the quotient for the choice, I use the first `r@l, and to typeset `b.)1 and the quotient for the choice, I use the second `r@l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a somewhat unclear question!

As @Schweinebacke pointed out in his comments, you are using a table with a total of four columns.  In your reply, you argued, that you want those four columns to be grouped in pair of two columns.  I guess, that those pairs of two columns should be separated from each other by the `2.5in`, as you requested in your question.  If my guess was right, here is my solution.

(Please, try yourself to type your code in a more readable way.)

## Code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array}

% \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
% \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
% \setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

%% Global definitions in the preamble!  Maybe you also want to define
%% the indent here?
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex}
% \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.6in} % <--- will be added to the extra 2.5
% in!  Table will then be to wide to fit!

%% Define the new pair of columns.  I use the letter P as of Pair.
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\bfseries\selectfont}r<{.)}>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}

\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{3.) }In the preceding figure,
$\triangle\mathit{CEF}$ is an equilateral triangle with edge length
$x$, $\mathit{ABCD}$ is a square with edge length $x$, and vertices
$C$, $D$, and $E$ are collinear. $\mathit{APQR}$ is a rectangle
enclosing the triangle and rectangle. If the length of the diagonals
of the rectangle is $d$, compute $d^{2}/x^{2}$. 

% \noindent \hspace*{2em} % <--- what is this good for?  Maybe a
% centering would be the better solution?
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} P @{\hspace{2.5in}} P @{}}
    a & \frac{23 + 4\sqrt{3}}{4} & b & \frac{25 + 4\sqrt{3}}{4}\\
    c & \frac{25 + 4\sqrt{3}}{3} & d & \frac{25 + 4\sqrt{5}}{3}\\
    e & \frac{27 + 4\sqrt{7}}{3}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

## Final Hints

Some more thoughts about your code:

1. I have deleted a lot of unused package (`tikz...`)
2. You have to load the `array`-package, to have this code working.
3. As you now have the `array`-package working, you can enable the `>{cmd}` and `<{cmd}`-trick.  The content in the braces will act as command, whenever you enter (`>{}`) or leave (`<{}`) the column, the arrow is pointing at.  You can use that, to have the first column of your pairs to be in bold font: `>{\bfseries\selectfont}` and to add the dot and brace with `<{.)}` on the first column.  you could also use it for creating a column, which is in math mode: `>{$}` and `<{$}`.  This saves a lot of typing work.  In order to save further typing labor, I defined a new columntype, containing all definitions for one complete pair of two columns.  To give it a verbose name, I thought of `p`, which is already in use, hence I used `P` (with capital P).
4. It would be clever, to define all layout definitions in one place, that is the preamble.  I therefore moved your `\setlength`-commands up to the preamble.
5. It was than easy, to eliminate your definition of `tabcolsep` for all tables at once.  Please bear in mind, that this value will be inserted between every column of a table.  You can prohibit that by using `@{}`, but I judge it neither elegant nor usefull in your special case.
6. You should consider, to do all your layout definitions consistently in the preamble.  I noticed a lot of usage of `\noindent` in your little example.  Maybe it would make more sense, to define `\setlength{parindent}{0pt}` in the preamble.  Than you don't need to type `\noindent` any more.
7. I was wondering, what your `\noindent\hspace*{2em}` is good for.  I commented it out and inserted an centering environment instead.
8. After all, I think, you are preparing some kind of examination for school.  In that case, you should think about using some special classes or packages like `exam` and Co, wich are exactly build, to support those tasks.  They even have counters for points, and blind answers, ...

Comment: The display that you got looks like the display that I got after I included `@{\hspace{2.5in}}`.  The space between the columns in the display looked more than 2.5 inches.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire finally I am glad, I was guessing your need correct.  I am quite sure, that `@{\hspace{2.5in}` will result in exactly that space.  If you doubt it, use `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` into your preamble and use `@{\fbox{\hspace{2.5in}}` in your table, to be able to apply a ruler and to prove the length.